# MySQL Select everything right of character if it exists

Tags: mysql

I need a query that only runs if a string contains a certain character, then select everything after it, if it does and set it in a variable.

For example, if I have 2 strings `101| 999` and `101`, i need to be able to say if the string contains `|` then select the 3 numbers after it and set them as variable `@ID`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: share your correct input output format. It will help to understand your query clear!

Comment: @KMS what do you mean sorry?

Comment: share your expected input and output

Comment: My expected input is `101|999` as a string, and my expected output needs to be 999 as an integer if the string contains a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(column_name, INSTR(column_name, '|')+1) into variable_name from table_name where column_name like '%|%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(<fieldname>,'|', -1) FROM `<table name>` WHERE <fieldname> LIKE "%|%";
```

May it will help

Comment: Im not sure this will work, i need to be able to run it in an if statement. The code may run 500 times, and for each time it runs I need it to check if it contains a pipe or not, and if it does, set the variable to equal the 3 numbers after it, if it doesnt, do something else

Comment: oh..once you try with this code if you want, andif any pbm share here